# iTerm and Terminal not showing Route:List as Table

Tags: laravel, terminal, iterm2

I have currently the problem that my terminal and iTerm is not showing php artisan route:list as table.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Laravel is 9+ version,recently updated Route list,
Check in offical website https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#improved-route-list